# How can I pass a changeable number of paramaters in a function by using one variable in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to pass multiple parameters in a function, depending on the size of a dictionary. The function is called "w.create_line" and is already working fine. When I pass the parameters manually by replacing linecontent with the numbers which are saved in linecontent, it works, but somehow it doesn't just work with linecontent in this case.

Linecontent contains a changeable number of integers separated by commas. The commas themselves are saved in linecontent. This may be the issue, but I can't find a better way around it. How do I pass multiple parameters to a function, when I do not know how many there are, because it's different every time?

```
while (counter < len(dic) - 1):
    counter2 = 1
    linecontent = ""
    polygondata = dic[counter]
    while (counter2 < len(polygondata)):
        linecontent = linecontent + polygondata[counter2] + ", "
        counter2 += 1
        linecontent = linecontent + str((canvas_height - int(polygondata[counter2]))) + ", "
        counter2+=1
    linecontent = linecontent + polygondata[1] + ", "
    linecontent = linecontent + str((canvas_height - int(polygondata[2]))) + ', fill="#FF0000", width=5'
    w.create_line(linecontent)
    counter+=1
```

Comment: Potentially create a dictionary of the parameters and pass that in, rather than trying to pass individual arguments. You can then unpack it as you need to based on your conditions inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wrote:

```
class DrawPolygon():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        w.create_line(args, fill="#FF0000", width=5)
```

and appended parameters to a list with while. Now it works perfectly fine.